# Calculate area of a triangle with just one length and a tangent-relation(?)

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking through some old mathematics that I did 5 years ago and don't remember 100%.

Right now I am learning about trigonometry and have some problem with a question.

"The triangle ABC is right-angled by the corner C. Calculate the area of the triangle when c = |AB| = 3 and tan(B) = 4/9"

I've been stuck on this one for several hours now, can somebody please help me? :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with $\tan(\beta)=\frac{4}{9}$ we get $$\beta=\arctan(\frac{4}{9})$$ and $$\alpha=90^{\circ}-\beta$$ thus we get $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{b}{3}$$ and $$\cos(\beta)=\frac{a}{3}$$ and the area of our triangle is given by $$A=\frac{ab}{2}=\frac{9\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been trying to use this for some time now but I can't get it to work :/ Is there by any chance possible for you to explain it in more steps?

Comment: After I slept and tried it again I got it working by using your explanation. Thanks alot, have a great day! :D

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: $$\tan(B) = \frac{l \sin(B)}{l \cos(B)} = \frac{r}{s}$$
Who are $l,r,s$?

*Hint 2*: The triangle is right-angled so
$$ A = \frac{mn}{2} $$
Who are $m,n$?

Answer (score 1):

As we know, $S=\frac{bh}{2}$, where $b$ is the base of the triangle and $h$ it's height.

We are dealing with a right angle triangle so finding those quatities would be easier, note that:

$$
AC=h\\
BC=b
$$

And:

$$
\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{h}{c}=\sin{B}\\
h=c\sin{B}
$$

And also:

$$
\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{b}{c}=\cos{B}\\
b=c\cos{B}
$$

So:

$$
S=\frac{c^2\cos{B}\sin{B}}{2}\\
S=\frac{9\cos{B}\sin{B}}{2}\\
$$

Note that $0<B<90$, and using the identity:

$$
1+{\tan^2(B)}=\frac{1}{{\cos^2(B)}}\\
{\cos^2(B)}=\frac{1}{1+{\tan^2(B)}}\\
\cos(B)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+{\tan^2(B)}}}=\frac{9}{\sqrt{97}}
$$

Using ${\cos^2(x)}+{\sin^2(x)}=1$, we get:

$$
\sin(B)=\sqrt{\frac{{\tan^2(B)}}{1+{\tan^2(B)}}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{97}}
$$

Thus you obtain:

$$
S=162/97
$$

Comment: It is conventional to write $\tan^2\beta$ for $(\tan\beta)^2$.

Comment: Yes to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Call the lengths of the other two sides $a$ and $b$.  You already know that $c = 3$.  Because $\tan(B)=4/9$ then $b/a=4/9$ or $9b=4a$.  You also know that $a^2+b^2=3^2$.  Can you solve it from here?  Remember that the area is $\frac{1}{2}$(base)(height) and, if $b$ is the height, then $a$ is the base.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Do you something like this or am I totally wrong?   

a^2+b^2 = 36

Then take 36/(9+4) = 2,7692307692307692307692307692308

a^2 = 2,7692307692307692307692307692308*4
b^2 = 2,7692307692307692307692307692308*9

a = 3,328201177351374732110050400742
b = 24,923076923076923076923076923077